# I iteration using css

Tags: html, css

I have four grid blocks in my website. I need to paint red on first and last. Other 2 in the middle should be left as white.

How can I accomplish this without using Javascipt?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use CSS `first-child` and `last-child` property. Try running the snippet below.

```css
.containers {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block
}

.containers:first-child,
.containers:last-child {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="blocks">
  <div class="containers"></div>
  <div class="containers"></div>
  <div class="containers"></div>
  <div class="containers"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks guys, really helped.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `nth-child` here as well and target the blocks you want to.

```css
.wrap {
  width: 100%;
}

.wrap div {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 15px;
}

.wrap div:nth-child(1),
.wrap div:nth-child(4) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, This technique is more generic...Thanks a lot.